# Is AskDifferent the right place for bash questions?

Tags: discussion

If I had a question solely bash or bash-related, would AskDifferent be the right place to ask? Or is there another community more appropriate for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bash is a part of OSX then Ask Different is a place to ask as can be seen by the [bash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) tags.

For OSX specific bash questions e.g. how to set environment variables for GUI and what files are read when a Terminal starts this is really the main site (SuperUser is also OK with these as any OSX question here is also on topic there)

Bash is also on topic on Superuser - Unix & Linux - Ubuntu and no doubt others as a user. Some question re programming bash could be on topic for Stack Overflow but I think that is not going to be the best site.